C code to generate a delay of one steptime
I have a step signal, going from low to high at t seconds. I want to write a C code to delay the step signal by one step time. Step time is 0.5 milliseconds.
I expect that the output signal would be equal to the input signal delayed by one step time. The output signal is initialized to 1. Suppose, the input signal is named test_input= {0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0}, so the output signal should be like test_output = {0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0} . Basically, test_output(0)=0 and test_output(t+steptime)=test_input(t); I need a C code to generate this output

Unless you have full control of the hardware, and can measure out a busy-wait loop that fits the time, you need to give us more information. Like the hardware you're targeting, or what operating system (if any) you're targeting.

Suppose, the input signal is named test_input= {0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0}, so the output signal should be like test_output = {0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0} . Basically, test_output(0)=0 and test_output(t+steptime)=test_input(t); a code to generate this output

Do you mean this ==> https://ideone.com/BE1MLd

Is this actually a real-time system where you need a 500ns delay, or do you just want the output you showed?

its a real time system, the real time input signal needs to be delayed by one step time

@pmg - Similar to the one you have shown but first I do not know the size of the input signal, and second, i want to store the value to another variable, and not simply print it. What I want is like putting a 'Memory block (from Matlab), whatever the input signal is, the output will be delayed by 1 step time.

If you want a delay for less than a second - use usleep()

So... this? https://ideone.com/uWl8p2

If I understand correctly, there is a signal which is sampled every 0.5 milliseconds. Hence, I assume that there is some functionality to sample the signal and some functionality to process/store the new sample, i.e.:
    unsigned sample = get_sample();
    process_sample(sample);

To make it appear that the signal is delayed by 1 step, the samples can be buffered for one step period:
    static unsigned sample = 0;
    unsigned prev_sample = sample;
    sample = get_sample();
    process_sample(prev_sample);

